# Thread safety of SocketOutputStream

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, sockets

I know that thread safety of java sockets has been discussed in several threads here on stackoverflow, but I haven't been able to find a clear answer to this question - Is it, in practice, safe to have multiple threads concurrently write to the same SocketOutputStream, or is there a risk that the data sent from one thread gets mixed up with the data from another tread? (For example the receiver on the other end first receives the first half of one thread's message and then some data from another thread's message and then the rest of the first thread's message)

The reason I said "in practice" is that I know the Socket class isn't documented as thread-safe, but if it actually is safe in current implementations, then that's good enough for me. The specific implementation I'm most curious about is Hotspot running on Linux.

When looking at the Java layer of hotspot's implementation, more specifically the implementation of socketWrite() in SocketOutputStream, it looks like it should be thread safe as long as the native implementation of socketWrite0() is safe. However, when looking at the implemention of that method (j2se/src/solaris/native/java/net/SocketOutputStream.c), it seems to split the data to be sent into chunks of 64 or 128kb (depending on whether it's a 64bit JVM) and then sends the chunks in seperate writes.

So - to me, it looks like sending more than 64kb from different threads is not safe, but if it's less than 64kb it should be safe... but I could very well be missing something important here. Has anyone else here looked at this and come to a different conclusion?

Answer (score 5):

I think it's a *really* bad idea to so heavily depend on the implementation details of something that can change beyond your control. If you do something like this you will have to very carefully control the versions of *everything* you use to make sure it's what you expect, and that's very difficult to do. And you will also have to have a very robust test suite to verify that the multithreaded operatio  functions correctly since you are depending on code inspection and rumors from randoms on StackOverflow for your solution.

Why can't you just wrap the SocketOutputStream into another passthrough OutputStream and then add the necessary synchronization at that level? It's much safer to do it that way and you are far less likely to have unexpected problems down the road.

Comment: Agreed.. you could have a producer/consumer model with a BlockingDeque that the producers (writes) append to and the consumer (sender) pulls things off the front to send.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. Whether it's a good idea or not could be debatable. Personally I don't think it's _necessarily_ a bad to idea to do things that are dependedent on an specific implementation. There are so many other reasons why one might want to use java besides the "write once run anywhere" idea. If performance is critical, being able to run your code on any implementation can be a requirement you're willing to drop.

Comment: I know that either adding lock around writes or ensure that there is only a single writer by using a seperate thread and a blocking queue would "solve" the problem. Using a blocking queue would unfortunately add way too much latency for my requirements though, and while synchronizing the access to write would indeed make it safe, it would be nice to avoid if it isn't actually necessary.

Comment: If there is no significant performance hit (which there should not be) in adding the synchronization, and it's easy (which is it), why not just do it and eliminate a whole class of potential problems? You can then spend your time worrying about other things.

Answer (score 2):

According to this documentation http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/net/SocketOutputStream.html, the class does not claim to be thread safe, and thus assume it is not. It inherits from FileOutputStream, which normally file I/O is not inherently thread safe.

My advice is that if the class is related to hardware or communications, it is not thread safe or "blocking". The reason is thread safe operations consume more time, which you may not like. My background is not in Java but other libraries are similar in philosophy.

I notice you tested the class extensively, but you may test it all day for many days, and it may not prove anything, my 2-cents.

Good luck & have fun with it.

Tommy Kwee